# ThreadPoolExecutor shutdown API doc verbiage "does not wait"

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, executorservice, threadpoolexecutor

In the documentation for [ThreadPoolExector#shutdown](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html#shutdown--) it says:

> This method does not wait for previously submitted tasks to complete execution

What does that mean?

Because I would take it to mean that queued tasks that have been submitted may not finish, but that's not what happens; see this example code, which calls shutdown before it's done starting all submitted tasks:

```
package example;

import java.util.concurrent.*;

public class ExecutorTest {

    public static void main(String ... args) {
        ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(3);
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            final int count = i;
            executorService.execute(() -> {
                System.out.println("starting " + count);
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(10000L);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    System.out.println("interrupted " + count);
                }
                System.out.println("ended " + count);
            });
        }
        executorService.shutdown();         
    }    
}
```

Which prints:

```
C:\>java -cp . example.ExecutorTest
starting 0
starting 2
starting 1
ended 2
ended 0
starting 3
starting 4
ended 1
starting 5
ended 3
ended 5
ended 4
starting 7
starting 6
starting 8
ended 7
ended 6
ended 8
starting 9
ended 9

C:\>
```

In this example it seems pretty clear that submitted tasks do complete execution. I've run this on JDK8 with Oracle and IBM JDKs and get the same result.

So what is that line in the documentation trying to say? Or did somebody write this for shutdownNow and cut-n-paste it into the documentation for shutdown inadvertently?

Comment: @GhostCat: thanks but i can't help feeling this is a lame question. Got stuck misreading something and couldn't get past it.  appreciate the helpfulness and forebearance. :-)

Comment: @NathanHughes nevertheless, the question is good since it is clear, and you provided experimental data to back your assumptions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the doc of [`ThreadPoolExector#shutdown`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#shutdown()), there is one more sentence:

> This method does not **wait** for previously submitted tasks to complete
>   execution. **Use awaitTermination to do that.**

In this context, it means the **caller thread** does not wait for previously submitted tasks to complete execution. In other words, `shutdown()` does not block the caller thread.

---

And if you do need block the caller thread, use [`ThreadPoolExector#awaitTermination(long timeout, TimeUnit unit)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#awaitTermination(long,java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit)):

> Blocks until all tasks have completed execution after a shutdown
>   request, or the timeout occurs, or the current thread is interrupted,
>   whichever happens first.

Comment: ok both answers are good but this is more directly relevant in saying the caller doesn't block, which was what i wasn't getting out of this.

Comment: Re, "the caller thread does not wait..." There's a simpler way to say that: You can say, "`shutdown()` returns immediately." Likewise, "if you do need to block the caller thread..." can be simplified to "if you need to wait until the remaining tasks have been completed..."

Answer (score 2):

Full quote of the javadoc of [`shutdown()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html#shutdown--):

> Initiates an orderly shutdown in which **previously submitted tasks are executed**, but **no new tasks will be accepted**. Invocation has no additional effect if already shut down.
>
> This method does not wait for previously submitted tasks to complete execution. Use [`awaitTermination`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html#awaitTermination-long-java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit-) to do that.

Shutting down the executor prevents new tasks from being **submitted**.

Already submitted tasks, whether *started* or still waiting in the *queue*, will complete execution.

---

If you don't want queued tasks to execute, call [`shutdownNow()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html#shutdownNow--):

> Attempts to stop all actively executing tasks, halts the processing of waiting tasks, and returns a list of the tasks that were awaiting execution. These **tasks are drained (removed) from the task queue** upon return from this method.
>
> This method does not wait for actively executing tasks to terminate. Use [`awaitTermination`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html#awaitTermination-long-java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit-) to do that.
>
> There are no guarantees beyond best-effort attempts to stop processing actively executing tasks. This implementation cancels tasks via [`Thread.interrupt()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#interrupt--), so **any task that fails to respond to interrupts may never terminate**.

Whether already started tasks are stopped depends on the task, as described in the last paragraph.

Comment: Of course, don't know why I got confused about this. thanks.